# mongodb, express.js app deployment best practices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an API written in `express.js`, the db is `mongo`. I'm planning to use [mlab](https://mlab.com/) 
to deploy the DB. I don't really understand where to deploy the express api? Can i use AWS for api only? Is there any provider where i can host my DB and API at the same time? What are the best practices for deployment of these APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best practices" is based on *your* needs. The current trend is to move everything to the cloud. So services such as [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/), and more will allow you to easily host your Express app with little to no setup/configuration on your end.

Each of the providers I've listed above have their own flavor of a NoSQL document storage.

- Heroku - [mLab add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab)
- AWS - [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)
- Azure - [Cosmos DB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cosmos-db/)

If you're set on NoSQL, then it's probably less of a headache for you to stick with mLab.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach in AWS for simple apps

1. Number of servers :1
2. Application server and DB server are in same machine.
3. Setting up mongodb and nodejs in ec2 server with nginx as web server.
4. Nginx  listen on port 80 and nodejs application running on port 3000
5. Using nginx reverse proxy to access the API endpoints